# Is $\{ pf : p \ \mathrm{polynomial} \}$ dense in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ with $f$ a Gaussian?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ be a Gaussian, $f(x)=e^{x^TAx}$ where $A$ is some positive definite matrix. Now let
$$
S= \{ pf : p \ \mathrm{polynomial} \}
$$
be the set which consists of all functions which are (multivariate) polynomials times the Gaussian $f$. Is $S$ dense in $L^2(\mathbb R^n)$ w.r.t. the $L^2$-norm?

Comment: Yes. This basically follows from the $n = 1$ case: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions

Comment: I thing you forgot a minus sign in the exponent defining $f$. + Nearly same hint as Qiaochu Yuan : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Completeness